# Best Practice in Module (file) Size for C

Tags: c, module, size

I have read that it is best to aim keep functions to no more than approx a screen full of lines.

Is there a similar guideline for module (file) sizes?

I have read several C programming style guidelines but cannot find reference to recommended module sizes (only that of functions)

I apologise if this is akin to asking how long a piece of string is - but I would be very interested in seeing if there is some agreement among experts on this?

Comment: i've since read a function should be no bigger than your head. The amount you can fit in your memory in one go? No put your head next to the montior, the function should be no bigger..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a separate `.h` and `.c` file for each `struct` and associated functions, and if possible not have more than a 1000 lines per file.

Answer (score 3):

I have been taught that module size isn't the issue, but rather code readability. That is why the "screen full of lines" for functions is best, as well as lines no more that around 80-100 characters long, no more than 2 cyclomatic nests (for loop-if/then-for loop-if/then...), etc. As long as your code is organized, I don't see any real limit to the size of a module, as long as the principle of [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) is practiced when constructing a module. That is the real standard, which allows the user of your code to include, as much as it is possible, only what he or she needs to get the job done and not much else.

Comment: +1 but...80 columns must be a hard limit.  If someone reads your code with COLUMNS == 85, she has every right to complain that your code looks ugly and is unreadable.  If your code looks ugly with COLUMNS=75, you can reasonably argue that the reader should increase the width of the display.  Also, some day you will have to read code on a console with no X-display, and you will be very grateful that the code is narrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean file length, it should be as per the ANSI C standard. You can refer to stdio.h FILENAME_MAX. Note that most of the implementations support file name length more than specified in the C standard.

Dont make file size very large. On an average, the size could go from 1000 to 2000 files. But it depends on how you have written the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your source code manageable.  Separate cohesive units into modules and keep each module in a separate '.c' file and each '.c' file should have an accompanying '.h' file.  Following this system and based on the complexity of your project, you may have '.c' files ranging from a few lines to approximately 1000 lines. Those numbers are reasonable and are easy on your complier and platform.